# Automatically adjust row height as data changes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Note: I'm unable to use VBA/Macros unfortunately.

Is there a way to make the height of rows adjust automatically as their cell contents change?

I have a sheet with formulae that return data based on some other variables, and the results can range from 2-3 words to a full paragraph. I'd like to make it so that row heights adjust with the changing data, as making the rows large enough to accommodate the large amounts of text looks ridiculous when the result is just a few words.

Comment: Excel will do it automatically on unmerged cells if "Wrap text" is checked (`Format Cells -> Alignment -> Wrap text`)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to automatically adjust row height as the data changes:

1. Select the cell(s) you are formatting
2. On the home tab of the ribbon enable "Wrap Text"
3. On the right side the ribbon, click on "Format"
4. Choose "AutoFit Row Height".

[image: Auto fit row height by selecting the 2 options shown.]

Comment: Is this something in newer versions only? I'm in Excel '10 and AutoFit Row Height has to be manually reapplied any time the data changes.

Comment: It does seem to auto fit the row height reliably on Excel 2016. Maybe try format > row (or column) > auto fit height?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work go to ribbon and select:

"Alignment"
Click tab "Protection"
Make sure "Locked" is unchecked